# Plupload Onload show list of uploaded files

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, plupload

I'm using Plupload File Plugin http://www.plupload.com/. I spent a lot of time to search it on google and forums but did't find. I also read documentation for this plugin but no luck. My problem is that i want to show all previous uploaded images on window load. Here is my code Please let me know if there is possibility or option available there thanks:

```
<pre>
$("#uploader").plupload({
    // General settings
    runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
    //url: {{ URL::asset('assets/js/plupload-2.1.2/examples/upload.php') }},
    //url: '../upload.php',
    url: "{{ URL::asset('assets/js/plupload-2.1.2/examples/upload.php') }}",
    // User can upload no more then 20 files in one go (sets multiple_queues to false)
    max_file_count: 200,
    chunk_size: '200mb',
    // Resize images on clientside if we can
    //            resize: {
    //                width: 200,
    //                height: 200,
    //                quality: 90,
    //                crop: false // crop to exact dimensions
    //            },
    filters: {
    // Maximum file size
        max_file_size: '1000mb',
        // Specify what files to browse for
        mime_types: [
            {title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,bmp,png"}
        ]
    },
    // Rename files by clicking on their titles
    rename: false,
    // Sort files
    sortable: true,
    // Enable ability to drag'n'drop files onto the widget (currently only HTML5 supports that)
    dragdrop: true,
    // Views to activate
    views: {
        list: true,
        thumbs: true, // Show thumbs
        active: 'thumbs'
    },
    // Flash settings
    flash_swf_url: "{{ URL::asset('assets/js/plupload-2.1.2/js/Moxie.swf') }}",
    // Silverlight settings
    silverlight_xap_url: "{{ URL::asset('assets/js/plupload-2.1.2/js/Moxie.xap') }}"
});
</pre>
```

Comment: you don't need plupload to display existing images, just use it to transport them. Think of it this way...the actual file is gone to the server, so plupload doesn't have capability to do anything with it anymore

Comment: There is a plugin available [blueimp file upload] which provide this functionality but there i dont like their interface.

Comment: plupload plugin got a good interface it fit to my need. There should be this feature as well.

Comment: ok, you must be using the one with all the bells and whistles and table display. Copy the same style for existing images. Shouldn't be too hard to do. I use plupload a lot but create my own progress bars and callbacks

Answer (score -2):

pl upload has init option and under this option you can modify File upload methods like...

```
$("#uploader").plupload({
....
....
    init: {
                FilesAdded: function (up, files) {

                },
                FileUploaded: function (up, file, response) {

                },
                UploadComplete: function (up, files) {

                }
                .....
            }

});
```

you can use these methods to put your uploaded files in your list.

Comment: Hi Azadrum, Thanks for your response. How to link to my folder with FileUploaded:? Any idea plz? is there an event or method available for this task?

Comment: the "response" parameter of FileUploaded method is the result of your upload.php. So if you return the path of your uploaded image from upload.php you can use it to render uploaded image

Comment: Downvoting without feedback won't help anyone. Atleast state what is wrong with the answer to develop a better answer for the question.